# how I can dispose a frame created through New JFrame in java using NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing

File is created using `Project → New(Right Click) → JFrame Form`

I set title as `XYZ` and I am trying to dispose this frame using a button on the frame using `XYZ.dispose()`;

But actually not working

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: NetBeans IDE 6.5.1

Comment: May this can help - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994935/disposing-a-jframe-usinga-button-from-another-jframe-in-netbeans)

Comment: NetBeans 6.5.1 should not be used any longer. It doesn't even support any modern Java version.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `JFrame` this way (the way you have mentioned), *then `frame.dispose()` will not work* **as non-static method can't be referenced from a static context.**

As you are closing the main frame not any internal frame,

For particularly disposing that frame:

```
this.dispose();
```

---

You can also do the exiting if you want, get the job done via:

```
System.exit(0);
```

For specifically disposing that frame, rather add one more instruction to your closing function with the code instruction:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
/*an import required for this--> import javax.swing.WindowConstants;*/
```

This closes the main frame (not the same as disposing of internal frames!).